# datatables click even on last column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have datatables like this code

```
var table = $("#mas-vendor");
    var filter = $('.form-filter');
    var target = table.attr('data-table');
    var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
            if (processing) {
                $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
            } else{
                $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
            };
        } ).DataTable({
            "ajax": host+'datatable/'+target,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "iDisplayLength" : 10,
            "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
            "columnDefs": [{
                "targets": [ 0 ],
                "className": "details-control",
            },]
        });
```

and the html like this

```
<table id="mas-vendor" class="dataTable table table-bordered table-hover table-full-width" width="100%" data-table="masvendor">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                                <th>Terms</th>
                                <th>Cheque/Giro Name</th>
                                <th>PPN</th>
                                <th>NPWP</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

on json like this (just example)

```
$json['data'][] = [$val['vendor'], $val['country'], $val['terms'], $val['cgname'], $val['ppn'], $val['NPWP'], $val['status'],'<a href="javascript:;" id="delete">Delete</a> || <a href="javascript:;" id="edit">Edit</a>'];
```

And my problem is i need even click on last column (action) not all column, and how do i know if id is delete or edit. Can someone help me??

i wanna try use this code,

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'td a', function (){});
```

but i'm still dont know how to use it on last column

UPDATE : MY PROBLEM CLEAR!!! tq for Vicky_Thinking!!! ;)

Comment: if you know its the eight coloumn then u can use table.find('tbody tr td').eq(8).on('click', 'a', function (){});

Comment: okay i'm gonna try that tq

Comment: @AtalKishore : is not working, and nothing happening :(

Comment: sorry it will be `eq(7)` also see my answer there is working example

Comment: You use the id of `delete` and `edit` within your data for your buttons. IDs should be unique so can I suggest that you change them to classes with the name `delete` and `edit` and then you'll be able to adapt the answer from @Vicky_Thinking to: `table.find('tbody').on('click', 'a.delete', function (){});`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
table.find('tbody').on('click', 'td:last-child a', function (){});
```

It will make all rows of last column clickable.

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's the eight column then you can use

```
table.find('tbody tr td').eq(7).on('click', 'a', function (){});
```

or you can also use `.last()`

```
table.find('tbody tr td').last().on('click', 'a', function (){});
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2jn08rup/1)