# how to apply onclick on a specific cell of a table rather than whole table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Actually I am using a function that any cell in a table i click it gives its row index but i don't want it. I want if i click on cells of only last column it gives back the row index of that cell but only cells of the last column should have this functionality not others

```
    $('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
             var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  alert(row);
        });
```

By using this function i click on any cell it gives back the row index
This is code of my table

```
<table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                      <th scope="col">Name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Auth Provider</th>
                        <th scope="col">Auth Unique Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Match Id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Game Mode</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 1</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 2</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 3</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 4</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 5</th>
                        <th scope="col">Character 6</th>
                        <th scope="col">Match Time</th>
                        <th scope="col">Action</th>
                        <th scope="col">Schedule Match</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

        <tbody>
        </tbody>

            </table>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            var trHTML = "";

            $.ajax({
                url: '../php/admin/schedule_match.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {},
                success: function(response) {

                    var data = $.parseJSON(response);
                    var table;
                    //table.clear();
                     table = $('#tbl').DataTable(); 
                     table.clear();
                     if(data!='') {               
                      $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                         table.row.add([ data[i].name, data[i].provider,data[i].auth,data[i].mid,data[i].mode,'<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p1 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p2 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p3 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p4 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p5 + '>','<img width="100px" height= "70px" src=' + data[i].p6 + '>',data[i].time,'<button class="btn btn-primary delete" data-id-id=' + data[i].id + '>Delete</button>','<button class="btn btn-primary schedule" data-id-id=' + data[i].id + '>Schedule</button>']);
                     });
                         table.draw();

                }
            }
        })
        });
```

Now this is code whenever i click on a row it return whole data of that row

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    alert(data);
};
```

I want to only last cell clickable in row that when i click in last i returns data of that row except for last two cells in that row

Comment: Can you share your code for `<table>`?

Comment: @VermaJr. i have shared code

Comment: Check if this helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40298501/datatables-click-even-on-last-column

Comment: You're mixing native JavaScript APIs with jQuery, don't do that use jQuery.

Comment: See the last part of code and read the description... can u help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works as you asked for :

```
$('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td:last-child', function () {
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
  alert(row);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn641a8t/) example can be seen here.

If last bit of your code works for you then you can change the following for loop in you code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (var i = 0; i < cells.length-2; i++) {
```

and it should give you the data for the row except for the last two columns.

```
$('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td:last-child', function (e) {
  var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());

  var data = [];
  var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }
    if (target) {
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length-2; i++) {
            data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
        }
    }
    alert(row)
    alert(data);
});
```

[JSFiddle for updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/oz9Lkpmt/)

Comment: i have updated my code can u see the last part once again kinldy

Comment: I have updated my answer to solve your last part of code.

Comment: i want rather then click anywhere in row to get the data of that row i should only click on last cell to get data of that row

Comment: Updated my code, which will alert row and data of all the cells except the last two cells.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: How does accepting an answer work? [for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199138/discussion-between-rprakash-and---).

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
$('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
   var $this = $(this);
   if ($this.is(':last-child')) {
      var row = $this.parent().index(); // this is the same as your code that get the row

      alert(row);
   }
});
```

to get data from each cell without last use:

```
var data = $this.siblings().map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```

EDIT:

here is native solution:

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
tbody.onclick = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var data = [];
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if (target.closest('td').matches(':last-child')) {
        var tr = target.closest('tr');
        if (tr) {
            var cells = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
            for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
                if (!cells[i].matches(':last-child')) {
                    data.push(cells[i].innerHTML);
                }
            }
        }
        alert(data);
    }
};
```

Here is browser support for matches https://caniuse.com/#feat=matchesselector

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199152/discussion-on-answer-by-jcubic-how-to-apply-onclick-on-a-specific-cell-of-a-tabl).

Answer (score 0):

Just get the number of rows present in `<table>` using `length` and compare it with the index of the clicked row.

```
$('#tbl tbody').on( 'click', 'td', function () {
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    var num_rows = $(this).parent().parent().children().length;
    if(row == (num_rows - 1))
        alert(row);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#tableId').addEventListener('click', function(){test(event)}, false);

function test()
{
 let col = window.event.target.cellIndex;
 let row = window.event.target.parentNode.rowIndex;
 let table=document.querySelector('table');



let tablelength =table.rows.length - 1 ;

if( row == tablelength ){
alert("row" + row + 
   " -column" + col );
 }


}
```